# How to provide YTD, 12M, and Annualized measures in SQL Server data warehouse?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, data-warehouse, ssas-tabular

Project requires a usable data warehouse (DW) in SQL Server tables. They prefer no analysis services, with the SQL Server DW providing everything they need.

They are starting to use PowerBI, and have expressed the desire to provide all facts and measures in SQL Server tables, as opposed to a multi dimensional cube. Client has also used SSRS (to a large degree), and some Excel (by users).

At first they only required the **Revenue FACT** for Period x Product x Location. This uses a periodic snapshot type of fact, not a transactional grain fact.

So, then, to provide YTD measures for all periods, my first challenge was filling in the "empty" facts, for which there was no revenue, but there was revenue in prior (and/or subsequent) periods. The empty fact table includes a column for the YTD measure.

I solved that by creating empty facts -- no revenue -- for the no revenue periods, such as this:

```
Period 1, Loc1, Widget1, $1 revenue, $1 YTD
Period 2, Loc1, Widget1, $0 revenue, $1 YTD (this $0 "fact" created for YTD)
Period 3, Loc1, Widget1, $1 revenue, $2 YTD
```

I'm just using YTD as an example, but the requirements include measures for Last 12 Months, and Annualized, in addition to YTD.

I found that the best way to tally YTD was actually to create records to hold the measure (YTD) where there is no fact coming from the transactional data (meaning: no revenue for that combination of dimensions).

Now the requirements need the revenue fact by two more dimensions, Market Segment and Customer. This means I need to refactor my existing stored procedures to do the same process, but now for a more granular fact:

```
Period x Widget x Location x Market x Customer
```

This will result in creating many more records to hold the YTD (and other) measures. There will be far more records for these measures than are were real facts.

Here are what I believe are possible solutions:

1. Just do it in SQL DW table(s). This makes it easy to use wherever needed. (like it is now)
2. Do this in Power BI -- assume DAX expression in PBIX?
3. SSAS Tabular -- is tabular an appropriate place calculate the YTD, etc. measures, or should it be handled at the reporting layer?

For what it's worth, the client is reluctant to use SSAS Tabular because they want to keep the number of layers to a minimum.

**Follow up questions:**

- Is there a SQL Server architecture to provide this sort of solution as I did it, maybe reducing the number of records necessary?
- If they use PowerBI for YTD, 12M, Annualized measures, what do I need to provide in the SQL DW, anything more than the facts?
- Is this something that SSAS Tabular solves, inherently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my experience:

I have always maintained that the DW should be where all of your data is. Then *any* client tool can use that DW and get the same answer.

I came across the same issue in a recent project: Generating "same day last year" type calcs (along with YTD, Fin YTD etc.). SQL Server seemed like the obvious place to put these 'sparse' facts but as I discovered (as you have) the sparsity just gets bigger and bigger and more complicated as the dimensions increase, and you end up blowing out the size *and* continually coming back and chasing down of those missing sparse facts, and worst of all having to come up with weird 'allocation' rules to push measures down to the require level of detail

IMHO DAX is the place to do this but there is a lot of pain in learning the language, especially of you come from a traditional relational background. But I really do think it's the best thing since SQL, if you can just get past the learning curve.

One of the most obvious advantages of using DAX, not the DW, is that DAX recognises what your current filters are in the client tool (in Power BI, excel, or whatever) at run time and can adjust it's calc automatically. Obviously you can't do that with figures in the DW. For example you can recognise the person or chart or row is filtered on a given date, so your current year/prior calcs automatically calc the correct YTD based on the date.

DAX has a number of 'calendar' type functions (called "time intelligence"), but they only work for a particular type of calendar and there are a lot of [constraints](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel_dax/excel_dax_time_intelligence.htm), so usually you end up needing to create your own calendar table and build functions around that calendar table.

My advice is to start here: https://www.daxpatterns.com/ and try generating some YTD calcs in DAX

> For what it's worth, the client is reluctant to use SSAS Tabular
>   because they want to keep the number of layers to a minimum.

Power BI already has a (required) modelling layer that effectively uses SSAS tabular internally, so you *already* have an additional logical layer. It's just in the same tool as the reporting layer. The difference is that doing modelling only in Power BI currently isn't an "Enterprise" approach. Features such as model version control, partitioned loads, advanced row level security aren't supported by Power BI (although who knows what next month will bring)

Layers are not bad things as long as you keep them under control. Otherwise we should just go back to monolithic cobol programs.

It's certainly possible to *start* doing your modelling purely in Power BI then at a later stage when you need the features, control and scalabiliyt, migrate to SSAS Tabular.

One thing to consider is that SSAS Tabular PaaS offering in Azure can get pretty pricey, but if you ever need partitioned loads (i.e. load just this weeks data into a very large cube with a lot of history), you'll need to use it.

> Is there a SQL Server architecture to provide this sort of solution as I did it, maybe reducing the number of records necessary?

I guess that architecture would be defining the records in views. That has a lot of obvious downfalls. There is a 'sparse' designator but that just optimise storage for fields that have lots of NULLs, which may not even be the case.

> If they use PowerBI for YTD, 12M, Annualized measures, what do I need to provide in the SQL DW, anything more than the facts?

You definitely need a comprehensive calendar table defining the fiscal year

> Is this something that SSAS Tabular solves, inherently?

If you only want to report by calendar periods (1st Jan to 31st Dec) then built in time intelligence is "inherent" but if you want to report by fiscal periods, the time intelligence can't be used. Regardless you still need to define the DAX calcs. and they can get *really* big

Answer (score 2):

First, SSAS Tabular and Power BI use the same engine. So they are equally applicable.

And the ability to define measures that can be calculated across any slice of the data, using any of a large number categorical attributes is one of the main reasons why you want something like SSAS Tabular or Power BI in front of your SQL Server. (The others are caching, simplified end-user reporting, the ability to mash-up data across sources, and custom security.)

Ideally, SQL Server should provide the Facts, along with single-column joins to any dimension tables, including a Date Dimension table.  Power BI / SSAS Tabular would then layer on the DAX Measure definitions, the Filter Flow behavior and perhaps Row Level Security.

Comment: David, thank you for your answer. The problem with calculating those measures in SQL seems practically impossible looking forward.